# Change label color on MouseHover, based on X Y coordinates

Tags: c#, winforms, coordinates

Without over-complicating a simple issue, I am trying to get the label color to change as the mouse hovers over a certain area of an image. My code should explain the situation:

```
    private void picboxMain_MouseHover(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        int x1 = e.X;
        int y1 = e.Y;
        if ((x1 >= 155 && x1 <= 179) && (y1 >= 145 && y1 <= 160))
        {
            lblX.ForeColor = Color.Green;
            lblY.ForeColor = Color.Green;
        }
    }
```

However it will not accept the e.X and e.Y parameters which get the mouse location and assign to the x1 and y1 variables. Why will it not allow such variable assignment? I have successfully used this following almost identical function which works perfectly?

```
    private void picboxMain_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        int x1 = e.X;
        int y1 = e.Y;
        if ((x1 >= 155 && x1 <= 179) && (y1 >= 145 && y1 <= 160))
        {
            Form2 Form2 = new Form2();
            Form2.Show();
        }
    }
```

Why does this work and not the other?

Comment: Any errors? Do breakpoints get hit?

Comment: I suspect it is because you haven't forced the control to refresh.

Comment: the error is ' SystemArgs does not contain a definition for 'X'...' and the same for 'Y'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the `MouseHover` event handler, it doesn't contain `MouseEventArgs` in the second argument, and then add `MouseMove` handler with such code:

```
private void picboxMain_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    int x1 = e.X;
    int y1 = e.Y;
    Color color = (x1 >= 155 && x1 <= 179) && (y1 >= 145 && y1 <= 160) ? Color.Green : Color.Black;
    lblX.ForeColor = color;
    lblY.ForeColor = color;
}
```

**EDIT:** And also `MouseLeave` should be handled.

Comment: Oh man, how could I *not* see this? I *knew* "MouseHover" event didn't sound right! :p

Comment: Excellent this has worked perfectly, I thought it must have been to do with MouseHover event args